# Netty client sends TCP RST

Tags: tcp, netty, spring-cloud-gateway, tcpdump, reactor-netty

I see strange behaviour in Netty HTTP Client.
It establishes connection to server fine, has some traffic but then sends RST out of blue.
What could cause such behaviour?

```
22:20:03.954242 IP 10.15.12.148.48578 > 10.15.11.231.443: Flags [S], seq 3323902224, win 26883, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 1926569864 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:20:03.954467 IP 10.15.11.231.443 > 10.15.12.148.48578: Flags [S.], seq 1448779381, ack 3323902225, win 26847, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 1891133578 ecr 1926569864,nop,wscale 8], length 0
.......
22:21:10.153161 IP 10.15.11.231.443 > 10.15.12.148.48578: Flags [P.], seq 1251507:1251541, ack 3342082, win 425, options [nop,nop,TS val 1891199776 ecr 1926636062], length 34
22:21:10.153360 IP 10.15.12.148.48578 > 10.15.11.231.443: Flags [.], ack 1251541, win 848, options [nop,nop,TS val 1926636064 ecr 1891199776], length 0
22:21:10.156194 IP 10.15.12.148.48578 > 10.15.11.231.443: Flags [P.], seq 3342082:3342744, ack 1251541, win 848, options [nop,nop,TS val 1926636067 ecr 1891199776], length 662
22:21:10.157072 IP 10.15.11.231.443 > 10.15.12.148.48578: Flags [P.], seq 1251541:1251732, ack 3342744, win 425, options [nop,nop,TS val 1891199780 ecr 1926636067], length 191
22:21:10.157113 IP 10.15.11.231.443 > 10.15.12.148.48578: Flags [P.], seq 1251732:1251766, ack 3342744, win 425, options [nop,nop,TS val 1891199780 ecr 1926636067], length 34
22:21:10.159209 IP 10.15.12.148.48578 > 10.15.11.231.443: Flags [P.], seq 3342744:3342775, ack 1251766, win 848, options [nop,nop,TS val 1926636070 ecr 1891199780], length 31
22:21:10.159238 IP 10.15.12.148.48578 > 10.15.11.231.443: Flags [R.], seq 3342775, ack 1251766, win 848, options [nop,nop,TS val 1926636070 ecr 1891199780], length 0
```

Or like this

```
22:27:09.009601 IP 10.15.12.148.54830 > 10.15.11.231.443: Flags [S], seq 3322702283, win 26883, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 1926994925 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:27:09.009865 IP 10.15.11.231.443 > 10.15.12.148.54830: Flags [S.], seq 311749646, ack 3322702284, win 26847, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 1891558630 ecr 1926994925,nop,wscale 8], length 0
22:27:09.009874 IP 10.15.12.148.54830 > 10.15.11.231.443: Flags [.], ack 1, win 211, options [nop,nop,TS val 1926994925 ecr 1891558630], length 0
22:27:09.009986 IP 10.15.12.148.54830 > 10.15.11.231.443: Flags [P.], seq 1:518, ack 1, win 211, options [nop,nop,TS val 1926994925 ecr 1891558630], length 517
22:27:09.010190 IP 10.15.11.231.443 > 10.15.12.148.54830: Flags [.], ack 518, win 110, options [nop,nop,TS val 1891558631 ecr 1926994925], length 0
22:27:09.010939 IP 10.15.11.231.443 > 10.15.12.148.54830: Flags [P.], seq 1:5444, ack 518, win 110, options [nop,nop,TS val 1891558631 ecr 1926994925], length 5443
22:27:09.010949 IP 10.15.12.148.54830 > 10.15.11.231.443: Flags [.], ack 5444, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 1926994926 ecr 1891558631], length 0
22:27:09.011902 IP 10.15.12.148.54830 > 10.15.11.231.443: Flags [P.], seq 518:644, ack 5444, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 1926994927 ecr 1891558631], length 126
22:27:09.012316 IP 10.15.11.231.443 > 10.15.12.148.54830: Flags [.], ack 644, win 110, options [nop,nop,TS val 1891558633 ecr 1926994927], length 0
22:27:09.012359 IP 10.15.11.231.443 > 10.15.12.148.54830: Flags [P.], seq 5444:5615, ack 644, win 110, options [nop,nop,TS val 1891558633 ecr 1926994927], length 171
22:27:09.012606 IP 10.15.12.148.54830 > 10.15.11.231.443: Flags [P.], seq 644:1306, ack 5615, win 435, options [nop,nop,TS val 1926994928 ecr 1891558633], length 662
22:27:09.014344 IP 10.15.11.231.443 > 10.15.12.148.54830: Flags [P.], seq 5615:5806, ack 1306, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 1891558635 ecr 1926994928], length 191
22:27:09.014461 IP 10.15.11.231.443 > 10.15.12.148.54830: Flags [P.], seq 5806:5840, ack 1306, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 1891558635 ecr 1926994928], length 34
22:27:09.014630 IP 10.15.12.148.54830 > 10.15.11.231.443: Flags [P.], seq 1306:1337, ack 5840, win 520, options [nop,nop,TS val 1926994930 ecr 1891558635], length 31
22:27:09.014658 IP 10.15.12.148.54830 > 10.15.11.231.443: Flags [R.], seq 1337, ack 5840, win 520, options [nop,nop,TS val 1926994930 ecr 1891558635], length 0
22:27:09.014831 IP 10.15.11.231.443 > 10.15.12.148.54830: Flags [F.], seq 5840, ack 1337, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 1891558635 ecr 1926994930], length 0
22:27:09.014849 IP 10.15.12.148.54830 > 10.15.11.231.443: Flags [R], seq 3322703620, win 0, length 0
```

Comment: It is probably closing the connection while there is still unread data in the socket receive buffer. There are other causes but this is very likely.